# CosmosDB SDK python odata.error InvalidInput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-explorer, azure-sdk-python

I have a table in a cosmosDB where I would like to store some query coming in from a azure data explorer.

In data explorer (using python sdk) I run a query to filter and aggregate my data and I would like to push this query result into a cosmosDB.

I did set all the configurations and connection, but when I run the command `upset_item` or `create_item`

I get the following error:

```
azure.cosmos.exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError: Status code: 400
{"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-us","value":"Request url is invalid.\r\nActivityId: d8994113-504e-4198-9976-41316aaafb5f, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.11.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0\nRequestID:d8994113-504e-4198-9976-41316aaafb5f\n"}}}
```

this is how I configured the azure-cosmos:

```
url = "url"
key = {"masterkey": "my-key"}
client = CosmosClient(url,key)
database_name = "database"
container_name = "table"
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

for i in df:
    container.upsert_item(i)
```

`df` is the result of my query from azure data explorer

the error I believe is due how I am passing the body of the query to the `upsert_item`

Any advice about this?

UPDATE:
so I tried to follow the sample. I updated my cosmosdb to a sql API.

my current code now looks like this:

```
url = "url"
key = {"masterkey": "my-key"}
client = CosmosClient(url,key)
database_name = "database"
container_name = "table"
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
data = json.dumps(test)
data_dict = json.loads(data)
for i in data_dict:
    container.create_item(body=i)
```

I converted the data frame to a json. but when I run the `for` I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

And I have no idea what am I doing wrong

Comment: I take it 'df' is a DataFrame, right? I believe this issue has nothing to do with Azure Data Explorer. Please make sure you can upsert an arbitrary data frame into CosmosDB first.

Comment: @VladikBranevich thank you so much for your time and reply. And yes, the `df` is coming from a data frame, which I thought it was a json by default. Any advice about how can I convert this data to json before to pass it to the upsert_item?

Comment: Here's a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-python#clone-the-sample-application) for cosmosdb-python sdk, I'd compared your code with it, the difference is **df** indeed. And it's true there's a json object in the sample code. So I think you'd better add details on how you obtain the df, so that we can know the issue.

Comment: @TinyWang I just updated my topic with the new update.

Comment: Btw, I tried the sample data in your another question and even I didn't set id property, I can still create items successfully and id will generate automatically when inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply and I think we need more contact on debug.

Here's my code and it worked well.

```
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey,ProxyConfiguration
import family

# Initialize the Cosmos client
endpoint = "https://cosmosdb_name.documents.azure.com:443/"
key = 'primary_key_in_keys_blade'

client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
database_name = 'AzureSampleFamilyDatabase'
database = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id=database_name)
# </create_database_if_not_exists>

# <create_container_if_not_exists>
container_name = 'FamilyContainer'
container = database.create_container_if_not_exists(
    id=container_name, 
    partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/lastName"),
    offer_throughput=400
)

family_items_to_create = [
    {
        "id":"112233",
        "name":"andersen"
    },
    {
        "id":"455646",
        "name":"johnson"
    },
    {
        "id":"999999",
        "name":"smith"
    }
]
 # <create_item>
for family_item in family_items_to_create:
    container.upsert_item(body=family_item)
```

Per your error, I think you need to check the data format of `data_dict` or you can use my sample data for testing to rule out other problems. In my position, I don't know why you'd like to use `json.loads()` here.